# Xamarin forms, bind to observable collection and update on new item

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im building something rather simple.

I have 2 pages and a DataAccess.cs in play.

Page 1 - list of items.
Page 2 - creation of items.
DataAccess - saves items in DB and has ObervableCollection **Items**.

Page 1 - Has listView bound to collection.

```
this.BindingContext = new DataAccess();      
ItemsListView.SetBinding(ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, "Items");
```

It loads as expected with the items from the Db.

I then go to page 2 to create new item which in the end calls DataAccess Save:

```
public int DoSaveItem(Exercise newItem)
{
  lock (collisionLock)
  {
  _database.Insert(newItem);
    Debug.WriteLine($"New id: {newItem.Id}");
    return newItem.Id;
  }
}
```

The page 2 function calls DoSave and then Navigation.PopAsync.

Which returns me to page 1.

NewItem is not presented in the list.

What am I forgetting, or what am I misunderstanding here?

Anyone please help :) I want my collection to be updated when going back.

If i just update the list manually in "OnAppear" i dont get the idea of an obervableCollection?

Regards, a confused programmer :)

Comment: page2 saves an item to the db, but it does not add it to the ObservableCollection, so page1 has no idea a new item has been added.  You either need to update the collection from page2, or have page1 refresh from the db when it loads

Comment: I tried to add the item to the collection in my DoSaveItem function, same result.

Comment: are you adding it to the same **instance** of the collection?  In your example Page1 creates a new copy of DataAccess to use as a binding context.  Does it share that copy of DataAccess with Page2?